make a colum total in flutter datatable
i would very appreciate any one who can help. I wan to make a column in a table which is come from summarize of col 1 + col 2 + col 3 in every row i tried this code but the result is not summarize but likes concatenate from col 1 and col 2...
rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
                snapshot.data!.length,
                (index) {
                  var data = snapshot.data![index];
                  return DataRow(
                      color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
                          index % 2 == 1
                              ? const Color.fromRGBO(34, 150, 243, 0.2)
                              : const Color.fromARGB(0, 140, 233, 148)),
                      cells: [
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            (Format.convertTo(
                                double.tryParse(data.lapus1_n1), 0)),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            (Format.convertTo(
                                double.tryParse(data.lapus2_n1), 0)),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                          //textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            (Format.convertTo(
                                double.tryParse(data.lapus3_n1), 0)),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            (Format.convertTo(
                                double.tryParse(
                                    data.lapus2_n1 + data.lapus3_n1),
                                0)),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]);
                },
              ).toList(),

the output is like this:
enter image description here

change the below code like this and let me know,
 (Format.convertTo((double.tryParse(data.lapus2_n1) + double.tryParse(data.lapus3_n1)),0)),

issues is you try to add the string then try to parse it. just parse both value then add.
rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
            snapshot.data!.length,
            (index) {
              var data = snapshot.data![index];
              return DataRow(
                  color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
                      index % 2 == 1
                          ? const Color.fromRGBO(34, 150, 243, 0.2)
                          : const Color.fromARGB(0, 140, 233, 148)),
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        (Format.convertTo(
                            double.tryParse(data.lapus1_n1), 0)),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        (Format.convertTo(
                            double.tryParse(data.lapus2_n1), 0)),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                      //textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        (Format.convertTo(
                            double.tryParse(data.lapus3_n1), 0)),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                         (Format.convertTo((double.tryParse(data.lapus2_n1) + double.tryParse(data.lapus3_n1)),0)),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 17, 17),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]);
            },
          ).toList(),


the syntax is underline red (error) and the message appear like this:
This requires the 'records' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.19.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.
and minimum SDK is already 2.19.0

updated the whole part let me know

I just copy paste the code but still not working:
The named parameter 'style' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'style'.

apologies i have added some extra '(' can you check now

thx very-very much Sir, it's work!! need to add "!" as a null check at the end of parse like this:
double.tryParse(data.lapus1_n1)!

@AhmadRifai happy coding.. if helpful upvote and accept the answer

i've already accept the answer but i can not upvote because my reputation is no 15 or greater..
